# What are the directories and files that I should keep in sync for a cluster server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, load-balancing, cluster

I am currently wanting to set up new clusters.

Each cluster is defined by its software installed, software settings, and its home folder files.

I want only the above to be cloned and not things like:

- `/etc/network/interfaces`
- `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`
- `/etc/hostname`

And please help with other things that need to be unique so that not to cause the system to malfunction? For example when reading [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem/TAR) article on tar backups, I noticed that they said not to include

> "/proc, /sys, /mnt, /media, /run and /dev directories in root"

---

So what I am wanting to be able to do is, create a new ubuntu 14.04 LTS server from [scaleway.com](https://www.scaleway.com/) and send a .tar across with all the system files needed above. After that I will be expected to customise the `/etc/network/interfaces`, `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, `/etc/hostname` and whatever else you think I need to(?) And then I would like to use `sshfs` to keep all the important system files (as mentioned above) between the clusters, in sync that I may want to edit in the future.

---

I tried backing up the main cluster like this:

```
sudo tar -cvpzf /fullBackup.tar.gz --one-file-system --exclude=/proc exclude=/tmp --exclude=/mnt --exclude=/dev --exclude=/sys /
```

and then running this on the new [scaleway.com](https://www.scaleway.com/) cluster after moving `fullBackup.tar.gz`:

```
sudo tar -xvpzf /fullBackup.tar.gz -C / --numeric-owner
```

but I just start recieving lots of `Exec format errors`? (I think it may have something to do with the ARM architecture from a PI to a [scaleway.com](https://www.scaleway.com/) server [an issue that I want to irradicate]) This is an example of backing up way to much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend that you use a configuration management system like Puppet, Chef, Ansible, etc. to install your servers. Ansible is the easiest to set-up and does everything over SSH connections.

You can use solutions like DRBD to keep the directories that need to be exactly the same in sync (customer / website data).

Comment: So ansible basically runs an ssh command on each device?

Comment: You make a recipe and Ansible will make sure the server configuration is the same as the recipe. It will run SSH commands to do so.

Comment: Okay great, but how do I go about migrating this system first?

Comment: ansible can run locally as well -- no `ssh` required

Comment: As well as keeping the systems in sync. When I add a new system what am I supposed to do? My issue is that I already have 2 clusters working on a raspberry pi. I now want to add another system but one from scaleaway. How do I migrate it?

Comment: any content management system expect, that you set up - each  server has number of roles/recipes/etc.
So, when you add one more server, you should change content management system configuration, to add new server into a role.
Then, while new server will provision, content management system will configure your server as other.
So, try to use content management system, as @Jeroen advice you.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar case: installing OS, configuring os (IP Address, sshd, kernel modules), custom software (only tgz files, no rpm).
My solution was:

- Create custom live cd with configured sshd and root password (i used livecd-tools)
- Boot servers using PXE boot.
- Create a script, that connects to the booted server and configures it.